# How do I retrieve the original code from an Xcode Archive file?

Tags: xcode, xcarchive

I'm a newbie coder would like to get the lines of code that went into making a previous xcarchive file.  How do I do this?

Comment: You can't. It is source control for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I re-open .xcarchive on Xcode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14949043/can-i-re-open-xcarchive-on-xcode)

Answer (score 3):

The `Archive` does not contain your `iOS` App source code as this is mainly the `.ipa` folder that contains the complied app bundle so for these kind of condition you have to use source version control system like `Github.com`